# Frequency count across whole pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

Suppose a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f
 a  0  1  3  6  0  0
 b  0  3  3  5  0  2
 c  2  1  1  4  0  0
 d  2  1  1  1  0  5
 e  0  0  0  0  0  1
 f  1  2  1  3  0  1
```

I want to count the amount of times each value (on each cell) occurs.

The result should look something like:

```
value  count
0     14 
1     10
2     4
3     4
4     1
5     2
6     1
```

Note that on my actual dataframe I have values ranging from 0 to 15, including integers and floating points. So the answer cannot be based on the specific count of the values above!

Any help would be extremely appreciated! :)

Comment: So dataframe is not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.stack().value_counts()

0    14
1    10
3     4
2     4
5     2
6     1
4     1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then convert `Series` to 2 column `DataFrame` with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack().value_counts().rename_axis('value').reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   value  count
0      0     14
1      1     10
2      3      4
3      2      4
4      5      2
5      6      1
6      4      1
```

If necessary sorted `value` column add [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.stack().sort_index().value_counts().rename_axis('value').reset_index(name='count')
print (df)

   value  count
0      0     14
1      1     10
2      3      4
3      2      4
4      5      2
5      6      1
6      4      1
```